# WebOS : API to read Content of USB stick on a LG TV

Tags: node.js, webos, lg

I am developing a WebOS application and have to access data which is stored an UBS Stick.

As far as I can see WebOS does not provide an  Api (see http://webostv.developer.lge.com/api/webos-service-api/) for accessing data on a filesystem so they only way left is using a node.js service for doing so. I have a implemented a service which uses

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

I looked at various directories but could not find the USB stick which is attached to the TV
The content of "/" is:

```
 /bin
 /dev
 /etc
 /lib
 /media
 /proc
 /tmp
 /usr
 /var
```

/media which from its name sounds a good place for such content only had the following files/directories

```
/media/developer/apps
/media/developer/apps/usr
/media/developer/apps/usr/palm
/media/developer/apps/usr/palm/services
/media/developer/apps/usr/palm/services/de.jfricker.slideshow.service
/media/developer/apps/usr/palm/services/de.jfricker.slideshow.service/package.json
/media/developer/apps/usr/palm/services/de.jfricker.slideshow.service/service.js
/media/developer/apps/usr/palm/services/de.jfricker.slideshow.service/services.json
/media/internal
/media/internal/.VolumeIcon.icns
/media/internal/.sysservice
/media/internal/.temp
/media/internal/.wallpapers
/media/internal/.wallpapers/thumbs
/media/internal/downloads
/media/internal/ringtones
```

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58551101/load-json-from-external-storage

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this API. Unfortunatly one has to be a LG Partner for downloading and using all the  webossignage Features. Grr how do hate this..  Claiming to be developer friendly and providing nice tolols out of the Box and then such restrictions. Seems i have to stop my project :-(